# What's the difference between "Do While" and "While" "Wend" loops?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I've encountered a a `while...wend` loop. I'm used to the `Do While` loop, so I was wondering what the differences were between these two loops.

I did some testing (code below) and both seem to give me the same results:

```
Sub test_loop_1()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i < 10
    Cells(i, 1) = i
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub

Sub test_loop_2()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While i < 10
    Cells(i, 1) = i
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Also you can't use `Exit While`.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, your link is pointing to a VB.NET resource; there, it shows that Exit While does exist, but it not applies to VBA; [correct VBA link is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement).

Comment: @MarceloScofano - good catch.  Since there are so many answers given after I made the first comment I've deleted it as it's really no longer of any value.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An answer I referred to is no longer visible, but this answer still holds true.  While/Wend is a hangover from Basic and Do/Loop should be your preferred syntax because:

1. It supports checking the condition **before** entering the loop
   `Do While [condition] ... Loop` (zero or more loop executions)
2. It supports checking the condition **after** entering the loop
   `Do ... Loop While [condition]` (one or more loop executions)
3. It supports no specific condition
   `Do ...(some logic) (Exit Do) ... Loop` (one or more loop executions, potentially infinite)

Comment: Isn't there an "Exit While" in VBA? Also a user has commented that "While Wend" would be an older version of "Do While" maintained for backward compatibility. Do you know if that's true? @NeepNeepNeep

Comment: "Exit While" does not exist & yes, I believe While/Wend is maintained for backward compatibility.  Really, it's going to be Do/Loop that you should be using.

Comment: @vsoraas 's comment doesn't seem to be showing up anymore.

Comment: Just to add to this, `Repeat ... Until` is the legacy version of `Do ... Loop While` (though I do recall seeing a version of `Do ... Loop Until`, but I can't recall if that was in VBA or another flavour of Basic).

Comment: does wend not do things 1 & 2

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is much of a difference in their execution other than the syntactical options that `While Wend`is not capable of:

```
Do
    someCode
While (someCondition)
```

As for speed, I did a simple test:

```
Sub whileLoopTest()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim StartTime As Variant

i = 1
StartTime = Timer

While (i < 500000000)
    j = i + 2
    i = i + 1
Wend

Debug.Print "While execution time: " & Timer - StartTime
End Sub


Sub doWhileTest()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim StartTime As Variant

i = 1
StartTime = Timer

Do While (i < 500000000)
    j = i + 2
    i = i + 1
Loop

Debug.Print "Do While execution time: " & Timer - StartTime
End Sub
```

Results:

```
While execution time: 6,429688  
While execution time: 6,429688
While execution time: 6,441406
Do While execution time: 6,429688
Do While execution time: 6,449219
Do While execution time: 6,4375
```

Comment: As for speed seems pretty much the same to me. Why would be created a loop that is exactly the same, just without some features? A user has commented (and was deleted don't know why) that "While Wend" would be an older version of "Do While" maintained for backward compatibility. Do you know if that's true? @vsoraas

Comment: @umLu I would not know for sure, but it would seem logical that `While Wend` came first, and then `Do While` is introduced later with additional and better syntax and features.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don´t need "DO WHILE" since you may "DO-LOOP" without "While".

I utilize "DO LOOP" if I need to perform an action at least one time (or several times) with no implicit condition, as the WHILE-WEND forces.

Just for an instance, a kind of alarm clock:

```
  Do
    Display Time at screen
    Sounds a buzz
    if user confirm
       exit do
    end if
  Loop
```

Comment: Interesting, but that seems to be the difference between "do loop" and "do while loop". Not really what I asked for.