# How to update date n times for n number of rows?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm currently working on a 16 000 rows excel file

- Column B is the date I want to update
- Column H is the starting date
- Column I is the ending date
- Column K is the number of times date need to be updated (updated on n rows)

The idea is to display all dates from starting date to ending date in column B (one date per column).

You'll find below my current codes. I'm a beginner, it probably includes a lot of mistakes. Can you please provide me with some help, I keep getting minor error: 91, 1004, 5...

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim MyDate As Long
    Dim EndDate As Long
    Dim EndRowA As Long
    Dim EndRowB As Long
    Dim EndRowH As Long
    Dim StartDate As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    StartDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").Value
    MyDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").Value
    EndDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").Value
    EndRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRowH = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While (i <= EndRowH And i <= EndRowA And i <= EndRowB)
        If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            GoTo Continue
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value Then
            For k = 1 To ws.Cells(i, k).Value
                ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Select
                ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "H").Value + 1
            Exit For
Continue:
        Next k
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Main columns in the spreadsheet should look as follows:

```
Type    Date     Start date   End Date   #

A   01/01/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/02/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/03/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/04/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/05/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/06/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/07/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/08/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
A   01/09/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10  
A   01/10/2018  01/01/2018  01/10/2018  10
B   02/06/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/07/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/08/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/09/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
B   02/10/2018  02/06/2018  02/10/2018  5
```

I thank you in advance

Comment: I keep getting minor error: 91, 1004, 5 - so you are getting multiple different errors?

Comment: In your code you say `StartDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").Value` but you don't set `ws` at any moment. Also, this line `Date = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").Value` makes no sense. `Date` is a reserved word in VBA. You should use something like *MyDate*

Comment: Thanks for you comment @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I didn't notice the Date feature and changed it to MyDate. I assigned my worksheet but know i get a popup with "$H$1048576" do you know where it comes from? Seems like a problem with my EndRow

Comment: When you say *popup* , you mean you get a Msgbox?

Comment: Also, about your data. I don't understand exactly what are you trying to get. I supose `#` column is the differente in months between `Start date` and `End date`??? Because in that case, all your data which type is B are wrong (between June and October is just 4 months, not 5)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes the popup is a MsgBox. Regarding dates, it's written in the European format (dd/mm/yyyy), this way column # is the difference between End date and Start date

Comment: @vityata Only one at a time but it's 91 then I correct it and gives me 1004 then 6 then 5... Without ever being right

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output? I don't understand what are you trying to do when you say *The idea is to display all dates from starting date to ending date in column B (one date per column)* because you need more columns that available columns betweem B and K

Answer (score 2):

Just try this code and you will see the error you are making:

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    StartDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").Value
    Date = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").Value
    EndDate = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").Value
    EndRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").Address
    MsgBox ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").Address

End Sub
```

I guess that you have no value at the last row of column "H". This is `$H$1048576`. 
In general, the way you pass `EndRow` with `End(xlUp)` is a good option, try to mimic it everywhere.

---

Some improvement ideas:

- write `Option Explicit` on the top of the module. It forces you to declare variables and makes a quick check before execution.
- you should assign `ws` to a worksheet. The easiest way is `Set ws = Worksheets("NameOfTheWorksheet")`
- the loops you are doing should end on the expected way. E.g., for every `Do While` there should be a `Loop` written. ["Do While" "Loop" and "While" "Wend" Loop. What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728334/do-while-loop-and-while-wend-loop-whats-the-difference)
- `GoTo` statement in `VBA` is good to be used only in the sentence `On Error GoTo ErrHandler`. In general, if you remove `GoTo Continue` from your code, it will still avoid the second loop.

Comment: Hey @vityata Thanks for your answer. You were right about column H, a part of my previous code kept creating rows. I juts tried your code and assigned my worksheet. But I keep getting this pop up with "$H$1048576", do you know where does it come from?

Comment: @ClémentHurel - the `$H$1048576` is the address of the last row in `H`. You do not need the last row, you need the last used row. See how you have achieved it in your own code for for the first column. `EndRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` The same should be for `H`.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks! I did as you explained but then "If ws.Cells(i, "H").Value = Cells(i, "I").Value Then" generates an error 1004

Comment: I updated the code within the main question, you can have a look, it'll give you a better idea

Comment: i can't be equal to zero. It must be 1 or greater.