# VBA Code to add first 10 even numbers regardless of number of inputs in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into a problem when I try to add the first 10 even numbers in a column regardless of the number of inputs someone has entered into said column.

The issue occurs when there are less than 10 inputs (in my case 7) and I have tried to break the loop if there are no more numbers after the last one but it doesn't seem to work as it crashes Excel; most probably because it loops infinitely.

The original code was fine until I entered below 10 even numbers. When I did it would loop infinitely and crash so I inputted a forceful break in the code (hence the `Count=999`) but it does not seem to work

```
Sub TenPosInt()

    Dim Total As Integer, size As Integer, myRange As range
    Dim Count  As Integer
    Count = 1
    Set myRange = range("W:W")
    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

    While Count <= 10
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Count, "W")) Then
            Count = 999
        End If

        If Cells(Count, "W").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Total = Total + Cells(Count, "W").Value
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Wend

    MsgBox Total


End Sub
```

My Inputs are currently `2,4,6,5,2,4,6,8,1,3,5` so it does not meet the 10 even integers, however I still want it to run regardless (hence the `Count=999` line). The correct return should be 32.

Comment: "it does not seem to work" -- what happens when `Count = 999`? You may need to move that test to the end of your `While` block instead of the beginning, when Count = 999 should prevent any subsequent iteration.

Comment: Alternatively, `While Count <= 10 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(Count, "W"))`. Now there are two conditions which break the loop: 1) If count > 10 2) if the cell is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Do-While/Until` loop is recommended instead of `While-Wend` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728334/do-while-loop-and-while-wend-loop-whats-the-difference)).*

Here I use a separate counter for row and the number of even values (and stole David's idea of combining the two conditions in the `Do` line).

```
Sub TenPosInt()

Dim Total As Long, r As Long, Count As Long

r = 1

Do Until Count = 10 Or Cells(r, "W") = vbNullString
    If Cells(r, "W").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Total = Total + Cells(r, "W").Value
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop

MsgBox Total & " (" & Count & " even numbers)"

End Sub
```

*Actually I would be more inclined to use one of the other gent's answers, but I have tried to stick as close to yours as possible. (Also a good idea to check a cell is numeric before checking for even-ness.)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - here is an approach that uses a `For...Next` loop, allows for non-numeric entries in Column W, and handles the possibility of blank rows between entries.

```
Sub TenPosInt()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "W")) Then
            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, "W")) Then
                If Cells(i, "W").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    Dim counter As Long
                    counter = counter + 1

                    Dim total As Long
                    total = total + Cells(i, "W").Value
                    If counter = 10 Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox total
End Sub
```

Comment: Ben, i think we were on the exact same path there... thoguh i do have to ask about `dim total` in your loop; should that not be outside the loop as to not reset `total = 0`?  if it doesn't do that, then no worries, but i will say i've always treated it similar to `set` or `redim` where the memory for it is anew. (same for `counter`)

Comment: @Cyril, no, `Dim` statements are not executed like that, so `total` and `counter` do not "reset."

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a standard `for` loop across a range?  this would give more specific inputs for the subroutine.

---

*Description of what is occuring below has been commented out to allow for copy/pasting more easily.*

---

'Define your range (you use columns("W"), but narrow that)... assuming you start in row 2 (assumes row 1 is headers), move to the last row, of the same columns:

```
lr = cells(rows.count,"W").end(xlup).row
```

'so you know the last row, loop through the rows:

```
for i = 2 to lr
```

'Now you will be doing your assessment for each cell in column "W"

```
    if isnumeric(cells(i,"W").value) AND cells(i,"W").value mod 2 = 0 then
        s = s + cells(i,"W").value
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter = 10 then exit for
    end if
```

'Do that for each i, so close the loop

```
next i
```

'You now have determined a total of 10 items in the range and have added your items.  Print it:

```
debug.print s
```

---

**Edit1:** got a comment to not break-up the code in an explanatory fashion, so I have added `'` to comment out my explanations in an effort to make my coding portion copy/pasteable as a lump.