# VBA : the value from ComboBox in IF THEN ELSE function

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm newer in VBA. I would like to compare the value from my ComboBox, for exemple :

[image]

With the value from my sheet :

[image]

Could you tell me if my code is correct. The result is right but I would like to be sure that my function are correctly indented. My code is :

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(ByRef strQ As String)
Num_Ligne = Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Row + 1
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "0"
Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "0"
    While Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) <> ""
        Do While strQ = Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) And Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Parametrage").Column) = "1"
        Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
        Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "1"
        Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "1"
        Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
        Loop
    Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: While indentation of code is important for future readers, it is not related to its correctness. This code is not indented correctly.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, I updated my code. Is that correct please ?

Comment: Indent does not matter in VBA, compared with python. As long as your code is produce correct result, then you can arrange the format until you feel comfortable with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cleaner view, if you prefer and try use line break when a single line code is too long:

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO(ByRef strQ As String)
Num_Ligne = Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Row + 1

With Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial")

    .Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
    .Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "0"
    .Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "0"
    
        While Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) <> ""
            Do While strQ = Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Chapeau_Partenaire").Column) And _
            Worksheets("6 - Liste des Partenaires").Cells(Num_Ligne, Range("Parametrage").Column) = "1"
            .Range("Calcul_CMA_Origine") = "1"
            .Range("Calcul_Perf_Contrat_et_Orient") = "1"
            .Range("Calcul_CMA_Perf_An") = "1"
            Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
            Loop
        Num_Ligne = Num_Ligne + 1
        Wend
    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @KingSiang thank you. I have a question : why I need to use While twice. I mean, when I use only Do While, the result is wrong.

Comment: I think this thread answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728334/do-while-loop-and-while-wend-loop-whats-the-difference , i think the different is about check condition `before` and `after` the loop. Although i rarely use `do while` or while` in most case to prevent infinite loop, especially in large vba program, `while` statement may cause infinitely very often when invoke function, `for loop` work the best as we define a range for it.